# facebook app says 'install' instead of 'allow' with oauth dialog

Tags: facebook

I'm using

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&scope=email&redirect_uri={1}
```

but the dialog box says "install" instead of "allow",

What do I have to do to make it say allow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in developers.facebook.com 
go to Settings > Advanced : Enhanced Auth Dialog: select  "Disabled"

Using the old Auth dialog displays "allow" instead of "install"